# Tridion Search is not working

Tags: search, 5.3

I am facing issue with Tridion Search in Tridion R5.3 where if I try to search something, although few results are coming but not all. For example: if there are 10 components which contain the text Example in them and I try to search for component with text `Example`, it may result only 4 or 5 out of them. Further, it was used to work earlier perfectly fine but now recently it has started giving problem.

What I have tried so far:

There are maintenance tasks schedules as per the Tridion Recommendation. The tasks are as below and are working fine:

- Scheduled to Run Daily:

  `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Verity\_nti40\bin\mkvdk.exe" -charmap utf8 -locale uni -optimize tuneup -collection "C:\Program Files (x86)\Tridion\Search"`
- Scheduled to Run Weekly:

  `net stop "Tridion Content Manager Search"
  "C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Verity\_nti40\bin\mkvdk" -charmap utf8 -locale uni -optimize maxclean -collection "C:\Program Files (x86)\Tridion\Search"
  net start "Tridion Content Manager Search"`

I have tried these commands individually as well but no success.

I have also tried running the `Tridion Search Synchronizer` tool as well for rebuilding the index. The tool finishes without error but issue still remains.

Am I missing any step or anything that I can give a try. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Also worth checking any permission issue, do you see any change (size, timestamp) in "C:\Program Files (x86)\Tridion\Search" after running above commands?

Answer (score 4):

Can try some other option with mkvdk command may solve the problem hopefully:

```
Usage: mkvdk [<option>...] <filespec>...
Where <option> can be a VDK switch, or any of:
-about               Show the collection's about resources
-autodel             Delete bulk insert file when no longer needed
-backup <dir>        Specify collection backup location
-blocksynch          Set internal flag VdkBlockingSynchSubmit
-bulk                Submit bulk insert file(s)
-charmap <name>      Specify the character map to VDK
-collection <path>   Specify the collection (required)
-create              Create the collection
-credentials <user>  Specify user[:passwd][:domain][:mailbox]
-datapath <path>     Specify VDK datapath
-datefmt <fmt>       Specify date format to VDK
-debug               Enable debugging output
-delete              Delete documents
-description <desc>  Set the collection's description
-diskcache <num>     Set VDK's disk cache size (kbytes)
-errorcodes          Returns error codes with bad keys
-extract             Extract field values from text
-help                Print this usage information
-insert              Insert documents (default)
-locale <locale>     Specify the locale to VDK
-logfile <file>      Save output in a log file
-loglevel <num>      Set the VDK output level for the log
-mailboxes           This option is depracated. Use the credentials option i
ad
-maxfiles <num>      Set VDK's maximum number of open files
-maxmemory <num>     Set VDK's maximum memory usage (kbytes)
-mode <mode>         Set the indexing mode
-modify              Modify fields using field/value pairs from a bulkfile
-nohousekeep         Disable housekeeping
-noindex             Disable indexing
-nolock              Turns off locking (dangerous)
-nooptimize          Disable optimizations
-nosave              Don't save collection work list
-noservice           Prevents servicing of submitted work
-nosubmit            Don't submit work to VDK
-numdocs <num>       Number of documents to insert from bulk insert file(s)
-numpages <num>      Synonym for diskcache for backward compatibility
-offset <num>        Specify offset into bulk insert file(s)
-online              Flag for online Bulk Modify
-optimize <spec>     Optimize the collection
-outlevel <num>      Set the VDK output level
-persist             Service the collection forever
-purge               Remove all documents from collection
-purgeback           Purge in the background
-purgewait <secs>    Specify delay before purge
-quiet               Suppress all non-error messages
-repair              Repair the collection
-servlev <spec>      Advanced option for overriding service level
-sleeptime <secs>    Interval between service calls for persist
-style <dir>         Specify style directory for create
-submit              Synonym for noservice for backward compatibility
-synch               Perform work synchronously
-topicset <path>     Specify VDK topic set
-update              Update documents
-vdkhome <path>      Specify VDK home
-verbose             Output more information
-words               Build word assist list
-wordindex           Build word assist index

The <spec> for -optimize is a hyphenated string of:
  maxmerge   Perform maximal merging of partitions
  squeeze    Recover space from deleted documents
  vdbopt     Build optimized VDB's
  spanword   Create word list spanning all partitions
  ngramindex Create ngram index into spanning word list
  maxclean   Really clean (not for read-write)
  readonly   Make the collection read-only
  tuneup     Fully optimize for read-write use
  publish    Fully optimize for read-only use

The <spec> for -servlev is a hyphenated string of:
  search     Enable search and retrieval
  insert     Enable adding and updating documents
  optimize   Enable opportunistic collection optimization
  assist     Enable building of word list
  housekeep  Enable housekeeping of unneeded files
  delete     Enable document deletion
  backup     Enable backup
  purge      Enable background purging
  repair     Enable collection repair
  dataprep   Same as search-index-optimize-assist-housekeep
  index      Same as insert-delete

Error: must specify collection
Usage: mkvdk [<option>...] <filespec>...
Where <option> can be a VDK switch, or any of:
-about               Show the collection's about resources
-autodel             Delete bulk insert file when no longer needed
-backup <dir>        Specify collection backup location
-blocksynch          Set internal flag VdkBlockingSynchSubmit
-bulk                Submit bulk insert file(s)
-charmap <name>      Specify the character map to VDK
-collection <path>   Specify the collection (required)
-create              Create the collection
-credentials <user>  Specify user[:passwd][:domain][:mailbox]
-datapath <path>     Specify VDK datapath
-datefmt <fmt>       Specify date format to VDK
-debug               Enable debugging output
-delete              Delete documents
-description <desc>  Set the collection's description
-diskcache <num>     Set VDK's disk cache size (kbytes)
-errorcodes          Returns error codes with bad keys
-extract             Extract field values from text
-help                Print this usage information
-insert              Insert documents (default)
-locale <locale>     Specify the locale to VDK
-logfile <file>      Save output in a log file
-loglevel <num>      Set the VDK output level for the log
-mailboxes           This option is depracated. Use the credentials option i
ad
-maxfiles <num>      Set VDK's maximum number of open files
-maxmemory <num>     Set VDK's maximum memory usage (kbytes)
-mode <mode>         Set the indexing mode
-modify              Modify fields using field/value pairs from a bulkfile
-nohousekeep         Disable housekeeping
-noindex             Disable indexing
-nolock              Turns off locking (dangerous)
-nooptimize          Disable optimizations
-nosave              Don't save collection work list
-noservice           Prevents servicing of submitted work
-nosubmit            Don't submit work to VDK
-numdocs <num>       Number of documents to insert from bulk insert file(s)
-numpages <num>      Synonym for diskcache for backward compatibility
-offset <num>        Specify offset into bulk insert file(s)
-online              Flag for online Bulk Modify
-optimize <spec>     Optimize the collection
-outlevel <num>      Set the VDK output level
-persist             Service the collection forever
-purge               Remove all documents from collection
-purgeback           Purge in the background
-purgewait <secs>    Specify delay before purge
-quiet               Suppress all non-error messages
-repair              Repair the collection
-servlev <spec>      Advanced option for overriding service level
-sleeptime <secs>    Interval between service calls for persist
-style <dir>         Specify style directory for create
-submit              Synonym for noservice for backward compatibility
-synch               Perform work synchronously
-topicset <path>     Specify VDK topic set
-update              Update documents
-vdkhome <path>      Specify VDK home
-verbose             Output more information
-words               Build word assist list
-wordindex           Build word assist index

The <spec> for -optimize is a hyphenated string of:
  maxmerge   Perform maximal merging of partitions
  squeeze    Recover space from deleted documents
  vdbopt     Build optimized VDB's
  spanword   Create word list spanning all partitions
  ngramindex Create ngram index into spanning word list
  maxclean   Really clean (not for read-write)
  readonly   Make the collection read-only
  tuneup     Fully optimize for read-write use
  publish    Fully optimize for read-only use

The <spec> for -servlev is a hyphenated string of:
  search     Enable search and retrieval
  insert     Enable adding and updating documents
  optimize   Enable opportunistic collection optimization
  assist     Enable building of word list
  housekeep  Enable housekeeping of unneeded files
  delete     Enable document deletion
  backup     Enable backup
  purge      Enable background purging
  repair     Enable collection repair
  dataprep   Same as search-index-optimize-assist-housekeep
  index      Same as insert-delete
```